# Handling interruption for multiple AVAudioPlayers

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, interrupt

Is it possible to handle interruption by AVPLayer delegate when I have more then one AVPlayer?
I have tried few things to start again two AVPlayer after phone call, but still only one respond and started, the second one was paused and did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to keep an array of your `players` so that you can poll through them and pause/start each one.  You can add each to an array when you create the player which you can access in `audioPlayerBeginInterruption:` and `audioPlayerEndInterruption:`

Apple's docs imply that the interruptions only handle one `player` ...if the class had stated a method input of `players` instead of `player` then I would have said you could have just done a for loop to poll through them like the code below:

```
AVAudioPlayer *player; 
for (player in players) {

    [player pause];
    //or [player play];
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVAudioPlayerDelegate/audioPlayerBeginInterruption:

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've solved this already, but just wanted to log my answer anyway. I've just tested this on an IPhone (4.3.2), my application is playing two different sounds with two different AVAudioPlayers. When receiving a phone call I DO get an interruption for each player, for both interruption methods:

```
- (void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *) player;
- (void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *) player;
```

So you can easily re-start both players:

```
- (void) audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *) player {
  NSLog (@"Interruption ended. Resuming audio playback.");
  [player prepareToPlay];
  [player play];
}
```

Comment: Those methods are now deprecated.